# Get the Number of the Month in SQL between to Dates

Tags: sql

How do we Get the Number of the Month in SQL between to Dates

Example: between 2023-01-04   and 2023-05-04 (output 01 , 02,03,04,05)number of the coresponding months

if between  08 and 10 (08,09,10)

Irrespective of the date

Comment: A calendar table is your friend here. If you don't have one, invest in one.

Comment: Snowflake and SQL Server are completely different products. Which are you really using? [Edit] your question to (re)tag the correct product. You also tagged SQL Server 2008, which ran out of support back in 2019; are you *really* using such an old version? If so, you *really* need to get that finalised upgrade plan implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it as follows:

```
declare @start DATE = '2023-01-04'
declare @end DATE = '2023-05-04'

;with months (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month, 1, date) < @end
)
select     [LastDayOfMonth]  = EOMONTH(date)
from months
```

This would give you the following output:

| LastDayOfMonth |
| --- |
| 2023-01-31 |
| 2023-02-28 |
| 2023-03-31 |
| 2023-04-30 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/YxG3VaHa)

If you only want to have the difference in between (Like "1") I would use the DATEDIFF function.

Comment: Thts great ,can i get the last day of each month like  2023 -01-30,2023 -02-28 and so on.

Comment: Ive edit the answer to your needs. If that is helpful i really appreciate it if you can mark this question as answered =) If you have anything else, please let me know.

Comment: @malcolmrichard: Please do NOT change the question, when someone is so kind to answer your original question.

Comment: Apoligies yeah Thts what i wanted realluy greatful for your kind help